# R: Group average of all nearby points in x and y coordinates

Tags: r

I have some data that involves a success/fail variable for many different locations with X-Y coordinates (integers between roughly 0 and 80 for both). I want to model the expected probability at any particular location. I can do this pretty easily using plyr:

```
sucProp <- ddply(df, .(xcrd,ycrd), function(x) data.frame(obs=nrow(x),prop=mean(x$success)))
```

This gives me the proportion of successes at each coordinate. As the success rate at one point should be similar to that at nearby points I was wondering how I can best take the average successes of all points within say +-5 in both the X and Y direction.

So the (25,50) point will take the average of all observations within (20-30,45-55).

What is the best way to do this? Can I input this straight into the .variables in ddply or do I have to work out some sort of rolling index?

Comment: An example would be really helpful here. I have ideas but I prefer to make my mistakes or successes after banging my head against a solid wall of data.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do a rolling mean of sorts. Here's one way to do it with sapply:

```
data.frame(
    x = rnorm(10, 40, 5),
    y = rnorm(10, 50, 7),
    success = rbinom(10, 1, .4)) -> ff

newmean <- function(q) {
    ff[q,"x"] + 5 -> a
    ff[q,"x"] - 5 -> b
    ff[q,"y"] + 5 -> c
    ff[q,"y"] - 5 -> d
    ff[ff$x < a & ff$x >b & ff$y < c & ff$y > d, "success"] -> k
    mean(k)
}

sapply(X = 1:nrow(ff), newmean) -> ff$neighborhood_prob
```